# Is it possible to limit the number of displayed items in a loop in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of categories and many questions which belongs to different categories.

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "description": "Does your site have Facebook?",
    "question_category_id": 3
  }

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Network",
    "description": "Network"
  }



<table ng-repeat="c in categories">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ c.id }}. {{ c.description }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="q in questions | filter: { question_category_id: c.id } : true">
    <tr>
      <td>{{q.description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code which displays all questions under a category.

But I want to loop through each of the categories and only display 1 question under one category by using AngularJs.

Is it possible ? 
If yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you even loop to display a single one?

Comment: hi @plalx , read my question please, it's about looping through categories not single question.

Comment: hi @MikkoViitala excellent~! your comment answers my question!

Comment: @Franva "only display 1 question under one category", that's what I said, why are you using `ng-repeat` to display a single question.

Comment: @Franve Did you try the filter limitTo:X?

Comment: hi @plalx what is another workaround if not using ng-repeat and not change the js code?

Comment: hi @Acsisr thx to your reply. but it looks like the limitTo only can be applied on array not on ui elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to iterate over `questions`, then you could use `$index`.

```
<tbody 
    ng-repeat="q in questions | filter: { question_category_id: c.id } : true"
    ng-show="$index == 0">
```

If not, but still you do not want to touch the JavaScript part, then'd I'd go around this using

```
<td>
    {{ (questions | filter: { question_category_id: c.id } : true)[0].description }}
</td>
```

Comment: hi @Mikko do you want to have a look at my new question ?  thx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277011/angularjs-how-to-generate-a-list-of-sliderbars-with-displayed-value

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of possibilities here, check de documentation of ng-repeat (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). For example if you only want to show the first question, you can check $first in ng-show on the tr-tag.

But be aware that this is only not showing the other questions of that category in the html, you still have retrieved all questions of that category from the server which is a waste of resources since you are only showing the first question.

Comment: hi @pkit do you want to have a look at my new question ?  thx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277011/angularjs-how-to-generate-a-list-of-sliderbars-with-displayed-value