# AngularJs how to generate a list of sliderbars with displayed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to have a list of questions and there is a slider bar with displayed value following each of the questions.

Here is the example how to do the data-binding from AngularJs website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But in my case, I will generate a list of my questions by using ng-repeat, so in this case, all the slider bars will have same id and name.

```
<div ng-repeat="q in questions">
        <span>{{q.description}}</span>
        <input type="range" id="{{'sa' + q.id}}" value="0" min="1" max="10" ng-model="{{'rv' + q.id}}"> 
        <span >{{"rv" + q.id}}</span>

</div>
```

As you can see that I'm trying to solve conflict ids by combining 'rv' (ranking value) and question id.

But I get an error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ''rv'' is unexpected,
>   expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{'rv' + q.id}}] starting
>   at ['rv' + q.id}}].

---

**Update**

I want to upload the list of answers back to my server.
The question model doesn't hold any attribute to store user answers. 
Instead, a model called: question_answer which has answer as the attribute to store the user input answer.

How to achieve this part?  Through $http??

---

**Update 2**

Here is the controller code:

```
var trialApp = angular.module("trialApp", []);

trialApp.controller('questionControl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.counter = 1;

    $http.get("http://my.azurewebsites.net/api/question_category").success(function (data) {
        $scope.questionsCategories = data;
    }).error(function () {
        alert("Failed to fetch question_category instances from database, please check your Internet connection!");
    });


    $http.get("http://my.azurewebsites.net/api/Questions").success(function (data) {
        $scope.questions = data;
    }).error(function () {
        alert("Failed to fetch questions from database, please check your Internet connection!");
    });
});
```

And here is the data structure of question_answer

```
{
    "question_id": 5,
    "answer": ""
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should just give `ng-model="q.rv"` and each question will have the property `rv` with corresponding value updated by the input. you have got the syntax wrong..

Comment: hi @PSL thank you for your answer. but the question model doesn't hold the rv attribute. I have a model called: question_answer which has answer as the attribute. Please have a look at my update. thx

Comment: ngModel can't be an expresion. It should be a field or object of your model.

Comment: thx @Callebe, then what could I do to achieve my goal? Sorry I'm really a 2 days-user of AngularJs. Please see my update. thx

Comment: Can you show us the controller code? How looks like a question object.

Comment: OK. I think your input shoul be like this: `<input type="range" id="{{'sa' + q.question_id}}" value="0" min="1" max="10" ng-model="q.answer">`. AngularJS will fill the answer attribute with the user answer.

Comment: Is Your API RESTfull? If it is, consider use [resource module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) of angular. It is really usefull.

Comment: Hi @Callebe yes, it is RESTFull. But to use resource module, it looks too complicated for me...any help please?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think your input shoul be like this:

```
<input type="range" id="{{'sa' + q.question_id}}" value="0" min="1" max="10" ng-model="q.answer">
```

Comment: Hi Callebe, I don't have q.answer on my question model, I use question_answer as a model to store the user answers. so I guess it will not work if I ng-model="qa.answer" as I have no idea from where to load the question_answer and how to initialize it in javascript....